# Split array into two individual arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have read in a file where boys and girls are separated by 1's and 0's. I want the boys to be in one array and girls to be in another. When I tried doing this, I ended up with 2 copies of the original array, where the boys started from index 0 up until a certain number and the girls started from the index the boys left off at until the end of the array. How can I split the two properly?

Code:

```
double boys[100];
double girls[100];
boys[0] = 0;
girls[0] = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < fun; x++){
if (gender[x] == 1)
    boys[x] = array[x];
else
    girls[x] = array[x];
}
```

I want two new arrays boys and girls that split from an array that comes from a function I made "fun".

Comment: No one will be able to answer this. You need to provide us with some code and detail what you have tried to do and what the problem with your solution is.

Comment: Provide some code, edit it down to the bare essentials, use dummy data instead of doing I/O if you can.

Comment: There is a code example

Comment: The supplied `code` sample has the following issues: 1. Declare your variables (what are fun, gender, boys, and girls?), 2. Base on your brief, it is wrong to reuse the same iterator for array, boys and girls (i.e. You should at least have 3 distinct iterators).

Comment: @StephenQuan With the code I provided can you give me an example of how to use 3 iterators with this?

Comment: In your code example, `fun` is implicitly and `int` but you explicitly state that it is a function but don't indicate how this is so. You don't define what `gender` or `array` are, these are implicitly double arrays? And the `boys` and girls` array are not initialize effectively. But, anyhow, I've see that you have already got a solution, so, nevermind my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"When I tried doing this, I ended up with 2 copies of the original array, where the boys started from index 0 up until a certain number **and the girls started from the index the boys left off at until the end of the array.** How can I split the two properly?"

The bolded part tells me that all you need to do is reset the index to 0 after filling the boys array and starting to fill the girls array.

edit: The code you posted indicates that your problem isn't what you said it was (at least not in the general case of potentially mixed boys and girls). You want something like this

```
int boysidx = 0;
int girlsidx = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < fun; x++){
    if (gender[x] == 1)
        boys[boysidx++] = array[x];
    else
        girls[girlsidx++] = array[x];
}
```

Comment: @user12074577 Just do `= 0;` after boys array and before girls array? Or use separate index variables to begin with?

Comment: could you help show an example of that with my code provided above?

Comment: whats with the boysidx++ and girlsidx++? where did the ++ come from?

Comment: @user12074577 ummmm...the C++ Standard

Comment: @user12074577 ++ after a variable name means post-increment, which in this context means "use the value of `boysidx` and then save the result of `boysidx + 1` back into `boysidx`".